# How to access and assign value to a variable using a string that matches variable name

Tags: swift, string, variables

I want to target a variable (a property) in a class by using a string equals to variable name. Is there a way to do it?

```
class Person {

  let name: String
  let email: String
  let address: String

  let propertiesMap: [String : String] = [
    "person_name": "name",
    "person_email_address": "email"
  ]

  init(_ data: NSDictionary) {

     for element in data {
       # string key address of Person property 
         propertiesMap[ element.key ]

       # value to be assigned to the property 
         element.value

     }
  }  
}
```

I expect to loop through the data NSDictionary and if the key of the dictionary matches a property of the class, then assign the value of the key in the data NSDictionary to the class property

Comment: If `data`– by the way don't use `NS...` collection types in Swift – contains deserialized JSON it's highly recommended to use the `(De)codable` protocol.

Comment: @Daniel, any update on my answer?

Comment: @SahilManchanda it's working, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way could be

```
class Person: NSObject{
    @objc var name: String?
    @objc var email: String?


    class func from(dict: [String:String]) -> Person{
        let v = Person()
        for element in dict{
            v.setValue(element.value, forKey: element.key)
        }
        return v
    }
}


func test(){
    let p = Person.from(dict: ["name":"John","email":"john@doe.com"])
    print("name \(p.name ?? ""), email \(p.email ?? "")")
}
```